# hibernate search case insensitive search is not corretly work with LowerCaseFilterFactory

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have following configration for hibernate-search:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "autocompleteNGramAnalyzer",

// Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),

        filters = {
                // Normalize token text to lowercase, as the user is unlikely to
                // care about casing when searching for matches
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class,
                        params = @Parameter(name = "catenateAll", value = "1")),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
                        @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "2"),
                        @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "5")})})
```

The behaviour is really strange.

I have field with value `George Cain`

if I search by `Ge` - it returns value
if I search by `GeO` - it returns value
if I search by `GeOR` - it doesn't returns anything
if I search by `GeoR` - it returns value
if I search by `GEOR` - it returns value

What bad with `GeOR` ?
How can I fix this?

Is it possible to debug this framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I customized `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` and now this works:

```
 @TokenFilterDef(factory = WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class,
                        params = {
                                @Parameter(name = "catenateAll", value = "1"),
                                @Parameter(name = "generateWordParts", value = "0")})//generateWordParts = 1 by default
```

Answer (score 2):

First, try to use Luke to see what has been indexed in your Lucene index: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases . You will be able to see the tokens, which might help you to understand what is happening.

Be sure your analyzer is correctly defined on your field and the analyzer is applied to your query too (might be a good idea to show us how you defined your field and how you execute your query).

If you end up thinking it's a bug, you can use our https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene to provide us a self contained test case so that we can take a look.

Comment: how can I recognize index file?